# Not able to connect to the mysql server at fdb3.atspace.com

Tags: php, mysql, database

My website is hosted by http://atspace.com and these are the details for my database:

```
host: fdb3.atspace.com
user: xxxxxx
pass: yyyyyy
database name: nnnnnn
```

So basically I've just installed mysql command line client on my computer (windows vista) and I tried running:

```
mysql -uxxxxxx -pyyyyyy -hfdb3.atspace.com nnnnnn
```

but I'm always getting the error:

> **ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'fdb3.atspace.com' (10061)**

Basically my question is how do we connect to a remote mysql server from a computer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure mysql to do so. Usually mysql is bound on 127.0.0.1 to be only available via localhost connections.

You need also to grant rights to the user.

If you have SSH to your space and it is bound to 127.0.0.1 you may connect via SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@atspace.com
```

Than you will be able to connect to your remote mysqld using `localhost:3306`

Comment: is it true that if the people at atspace can actually be rejecting my connections?

Comment: how do i configure mysql to connect to fdb3.atspace.com ?

Comment: if the mysql server on atspace is bound to 127.0.0.1 it will reject it for sure. But thats the usual way of configuring mysql. Most of the times ppl get a ssh connection to their space and may tunnel mysql over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

1.edit your `my.cnf` and disable

> bind-address 127.0.0.1

2.allow someone access your db server from remote server use this:

> grant all on *.* to
>   'username'@'ipaddress' identified by
>   'password'

the ipaddress can be `%`, `192.168.1.%` etc...

Comment: what do you mean by **my.cnf** ?

Comment: @Tingting, my.cnf is mysql's config file, it in /etc/ dir on linux default

Comment: when i tried to run the grant-all code on my sql database on the server, i get ` #1045 - Access denied for user '778736_uuser'@'%' (using password: YES)` ?

Comment: @Tingting your should run flush privileges after grant clause!

Answer (score 1):

Its usually very bad practice to expose a DBMS directly on the internet - unless you purchased a database-only hosting package from the service provider, it's very likely that you won't get external access - the machine should be on non-routable address or firewalled.

How you go about getting access to your database depends on what is available within the package you are paying for. One obvious solution would be to install [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) on your webserver , or ssh into your webserver and try to run the mysql client from there.

There may be further options available if these boxes are virtual/dedicated (i.e. you've got root access and can install your own binaries)

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting from remote machine you need to set up database server to accept remote connections.

How to do so? By visiting [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) link, you'll learn how to configure your server correctly.

You may find usefull informations in @Neo's answer however if you want to learn new thing, I'd suggest visiting the link I provided.